# How many ways we can choose items from different boxes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, factorial

I searched through the internet but couldn't find my answer, which can either be a very simple or a hard one.

Assume there are $3$ boxes, which carry, respectively, $1$, $4$, $2$ items.
My question is how many ways we can select $3$ items from these boxes.
I am looking for a formula rather than a solution for these specific values.

If I choose (take away) $3$ items by trying one by one.
\begin{array}{c c c}
0 & 3 & 1\\
0 & 2 & 2\\
0 & 4 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 2\\
1 & 3 & 0\\ 
1 & 2 & 1
\end{array}

Items remain each time, so the answer seems to be $6$ different ways. But I am not sure.

Comment: Yes there are total 7 items.

Comment: The items are not distict. So what decides how many ways are there, is actually how many items remain in each box.

Comment: Are the items in each box identical?  If so, you're talking about the number of sums $a_1+a_2+a_3=3$ where $0\leq a_1\leq 1$, $0\leq a_2\leq 4$, and $0\leq a_3\leq 2$.  Sums of this form are standard in combinatorics.

Comment: Yes, Michael. I guess that was the thing I was trying to convert my problem into. But if a1, a2, a3 are the items remain in each box, the sum must be 4. If not, it is correct.

Comment: I think the general problem you are after is this. We have $k$ boxes, labelled $1$ to $k$. The number of items in Box $i$ is $a_i$, given. We are also given a number $n$ of items we must choose. We want to find the number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_k=n$ in non-negative integers, with the restriction that $x_i\le a_i$. How many ways $w_n$ are there to do this? Not a simple problem! One can easily write down a generating function for the $w_n$, but computing the coefficients is messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that since the items are identical, it does not matter that there are $4$ items in the second box.  Your are then asking for the number of sums $a_1+a_2+a_3=3$ where $0\leq a_1\leq 1$, $0\leq a_2\leq 3$, and $0\leq a_3\leq 2$.  I will give three answers.

First, an elementary argument: We know that $a_1=0$ or $a_1=1$.  If $a_1=0$, then $a_2+a_3=3$.  In this case, there are three possibilities: $3+0=3$, $2+1=3$, and $1+2=3$.  If $a_1=1$, then $a_2+a_3=2$ and there are still three possibilities: $2+0=2$, $1+1=2$, and $0+2=2$.  This results in $6$ different options.

A more combinatorial argument: The number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of $k$ nonnegative integers is 
$$
\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}
$$
and a discussion can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217597/number-of-ways-to-write-n-as-a-sum-of-k-nonnegative-integers).
So, in this case, the number of ways that $a_1+a_2+a_3=3$ (without restrictions) is
$$
\binom{3+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{5}{2}=10.
$$
This, however, counts too many possible sums.  Suppose that we take too many from box $1$, this means that we take at least $2$ from box $1$.  In this case, we can write $a_1=2+b_1$ where $b_1$ is nonnegative.  Then, the initial sum becomes $b_1+a_2+a_3=1$.  Using the same formula, this results in
$$
\binom{1+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{3}{2}=3
$$
impossible ways.  Continuing, there is no way to take too many objects from the second box, but it is possible to take too many objects from box $3$.  In this case, one must take $3$ objects from box $3$, so we write $a_3=3+b_3$ where $b_3$ is nonnegative.  This results in the equation $a_1+a_2+(3+b_3)=3$.  There are
$$  
\binom{0+3-1}{3-1}=1
$$
ways for this sum to occur.  We should now use the inclusion/exclusion principle to see if we've over-counted.  This could happen if we take more than $1$ item from box $1$ and more than $2$ items from box $3$.  Then, we have $(2+b_1)+b_2+(3+b_3)=3$, but this has no solutions as a sum of nonnegative integers cannot be negative.

Therefore, out of the original $10$ possibilities, $3+1=4$ are impossible, leaving the $6$ that we've found.

A dynamic programming-type solution: Let $N(b,s)$ be the number of ways to use the first $b$ boxes to sum to $s$.  Also, write $m_i$ for the number of objects in box $i$.  In your case:
\begin{align*}
N(1,0)&=1\\
N(1,1)&=1\\
N(1,2)&=0\\
N(1,3)&=0.
\end{align*}

Then, the values in the second box can be computed as follows:
$$
N(b+1,s)=\sum_{i=0}^{\min\{s,m_{b+1}\}}N(b,s-i).
$$
Using this formula:
\begin{align*}
N(2,0)&=N(1,0)=1\\
N(2,1)&=N(1,0)+N(1,1)=2\\
N(2,2)&=N(1,0)+N(1,1)+N(1,2)=2\\
N(2,3)&=N(1,0)+N(1,1)+N(1,2)+N(1,3)=2.
\end{align*}

Continuing for the third column,
\begin{align*}
N(3,0)&=N(2,0)=1\\
N(3,1)&=N(2,0)+N(2,1)=3\\
N(3,2)&=N(2,0)+N(2,1)+N(2,2)=5\\
N(3,3)&=N(2,1)+N(2,2)+N(2,3)=6.
\end{align*}

We are interested in the value $N(3,3)=6$.

Comment: You are right, however I am currently constructing a computer program where I will deal with much bigger inputs. So I need a formula. These was just the values I came up to explain the situation.

Comment: The third solution should work quite quickly on a computer (you just need to run through a pair of arrays many times).

Comment: Forgive my dullness, but I didn't understand your last solution. How $$N(b, s)$$ is defined and how $$N(3,2) = 2$$ and $$N(3,2) = 5$$ in your explanation.

Comment: Cut and paste error!

Comment: For the calculation of $N(b+1,s)$: How many objects can be taken from the $b+1$st box?  At most $s$ or the number of objects in the box.  If you take $0$ objects from the $b+1$st box, then the objects must come from the remaining $b$ boxes, so you have $N(b,s)$ ways.  If you take $1$ object from the $b+1$st box, then the remaining $s-1$ objects must come from the remaining $b$ boxes, so you have $N(b,s-1)$ ways.  Continue adding these up until you run out of objects in the box or take $s$ objects from box $b+1$.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

Comment: This recursion failed me because I worked with problems with more than 100 elements(boxes) :(

Comment: What happened in the recursion?  Is it an overflow error or an out of memory error or ... ?  Could you try a language like Python which does better with very large numbers?  Perhaps you could add a link to a sample problem so that others could test ideas?

Comment: I am currently using python and there was no error, it just takes too much time. Because the integer count is more than 100(the list), it ends up in a lot of recursions.

Comment: I would like to try it myself, is there any way that you could share a sample?  If you want to do it privately, you can find my webpage in my profile.

Comment: I do not wish to do this privately but the thing is, the question I asked was not the actual problem. It was the part of different problem and it is way too long and in another language. Thats why I don't share the real problem. I was able to cut the problem into pieces and each part needs solving, and this is one of them. But I could post the python code of the function.

Comment: Please share what you can - don't worry about the original problem - I just care about the number of boxes and what's in each box.  (I want to write my own code to see how long it takes.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35712/discussion-between-rockybilly-and-michael-burr).

Comment: Please check your email.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that I came up with in Sage.  It takes about 19 minutes that is MUCH larger than the one initially posed (1000 boxes with random values between 1 and 1000).  But 100 boxes with values between 1 and 100 finished under a second.  Also, if you need a particular maximum value, just change $s$ to that value.

```
Boxes = [randint(1,100) for i in range(1000)]
n = len(Boxes)
s = sum(Boxes)
l1 = [0] * (s+1)
l2 = [0] * (s+1)
parity = 0
for i in range(Boxes[0]+1):
    l1[i]=1
for i in range(1,n):
    if(parity == 0):
        l2[0]=l1[0]
        for j in range(1,Boxes[i]+1):
            l2[j]=l2[j-1]+l1[j]
        for j in range(Boxes[i]+1,s+1):
            l2[j]=l2[j-1]+l1[j]-l1[j-Boxes[i]-1]
        parity = 1
    else:
        l1[0]=l2[0]
        for j in range(1,Boxes[i]+1):
            l1[j]=l1[j-1]+l2[j]
        for j in range(Boxes[i]+1,s+1):
            l1[j]=l1[j-1]+l2[j]-l2[j-Boxes[i]-1]
        parity = 0
if(parity == 1):
    l = l2
else:
    l = l1

print l
```

Edit: I cut out one of the loops, reducing the complexity.

Comment: Much better indeed. However, it is still not enough for the method I need. If I had found a solution in [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654423/how-many-ways-to-write-sum-as-k-restricted-integers/), I would have answered this question much better.

Comment: Using a generating function is a nice method.  I should have thought of that!  (Although the code above is (more or less) computing the coefficients of the generating function).

Comment: Yes, indeed. They are quite similar methods.