# How many ways to write sum as $k$ restricted integers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, factorial

If we have $3$ positive integers given as 
\begin{align*}
0 & \leq a \leq 3\\
0 & \leq b \leq 3\\
0 & \leq c \leq 2 
\end{align*}
and given the sum $$ a+b+c = 5$$

how many ways we can distribute these integers ?

Note: I asked a relatively close question to this but I was unsuccessful at applying that solution. Please do enlighten me.

Is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) page a good exploration point ?

Comment: You can obtain $\leq$ and $\geq$ by typing, respectively, \leq  and \geq when you are in math mode.

Comment: Do you understand how to solve the equation $a + b + c = 5$ in the non-negative integers when there were no restrictions?

Comment: Thanks Taussig, and I know how to solve without restrictions. I want to know how to rule out over-counts given to this restrictions.(I guess that's how it is done ?)

Comment: The page you referenced is a good reference for the problem of solving the equation $a + b + c = 5$ in the non-negative integers.  Read about weak compositions.

Answer (score 2):

A generatingfunctionologist would say that the generating function for the number of solutions in non-negative integers of
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = r$$
subject to $x_1 \le 2$, $x_2 \le 3$, $x_3 \le 3$
is
$$\begin{align}f(x) &= (1+x+x^2) \cdot (1+x+x^2+x^3)^2\\ &= x^8+3 x^7+6 x^6+9 x^5+10 x^4+9 x^3+6 x^2+3 x+1 \end{align}$$
The answer to the problem is the coefficient of $x^5$ when $f(x)$ is expanded, i.e. $9$.

Reference: Wilf, *generatingfunctionology*

https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html

Comment: Thank you, I am giving you +1 because you gave a nice answer for the question asked, however I didn't mention before but I am building a computer program, and this solution requires much memory, moreover the multiplication process with more than 3 integers(like 80-100) is very consuming indeed.

Answer (score 1):

A particular solution of the equation
$$a + b + c = 5 \tag{1}$$
in the non-negative integers corresponds to the placement of two addition signs in a row of five ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 1 + 1 1 +$$ 
corresponds to the solution $a = 3$, $b = 2$, and $c = 0$.  Thus, the number of solutions of equation 1 in the non-negative integers is 
$$\binom{5 + 2}{2} = \binom{7}{2}$$
since we must select which two of the seven symbols (five ones and two addition signs) will be addition signs.

From these, we must exclude those solutions in which $a > 3$, $b > 3$, or $c > 2$.  Since $a, b, c$ are integers, this means we must exclude those solutions in which $a \geq 4$, $b \geq 4$, and $c \geq 3$.  Since $4 + 3 = 7 > 5$, no two of these restrictions can hold simultaneously.

Suppose $a \geq 4$.  Let $a' = a - 4$.  Then $a'$ is a non-negative integer.  Substituting $a' + 4$ for $a$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
a' + 4 + b + c & = 5\\
a' + b + c & = 1 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the non-negative integers with 
$$\binom{1 + 2}{2} = \binom{3}{2}$$
solutions.

By similar argument, there are $\binom{3}{2}$ solutions if $b \geq 4$.

Suppose $c \geq 3$.  Let $c' = c - 3$.  Then $c'$ is a non-negative integer.  Substituting $c' + 3$ for $c$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
a + b + c' + 3 & = 5\\
a + b + c' & = 2 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equation 3 is an equation in the non-negative integers with 
$$\binom{2 + 2}{2} = \binom{4}{2}$$
solutions.

Hence, the number of solutions of equation 1 in the non-negative integers subject to the restrictions $a \leq 3$, $b \leq 3$, and $c \leq 2$ is 
$$\binom{7}{2} - 2\binom{3}{2} - \binom{4}{2}$$

Comment: What if this was a problem that, two of the restrictions can hold simultaneously. Because these values was just exemplary, I am actually going to deal with much harder ones.

Comment: Therefore I am looking for a more general solution.

Comment: @Rockybilly  Would you like me to write an example in which two or more restrictions hold simultaneously?  You can handle those situations by using the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) or [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function).

Comment: Thank you, I was indeed trying to generate a function to find the number of all possibilites, that works for all cases given in this form. The actual problem I am dealing with has like 80 integers, each having their restrictions.(I managed to get all restrictions to start from 0 as minimum point, because I thought it would make the problem easier)

Answer (score 0):

- Given the minimal number $2$, for each value of $c$ and $b$, thee exists immidiatly a value of $a$ satisying the sum. so

$S=3*4$

> EDIT: there is cases where no element $a$ exists which follows:

(0,0) and (0,1) considering permutations those are 3 cases so

$S=3*4-3$