# Number of ways to write $n$ as sum of $k$ non-negative integers without 1

Tags: combinatorics

During my calculations I ended up at the following combinatorial problem: In how many way can we write the integer $n$ as the sum of $k$ non-negative integers, each different to one, i.e. calculate
$$\sum_{n_1+n_2+\dots+n_k=n,n_i\ne1}1$$
for non-negative integers $n_i\in\{0,2,3,\dotsc,n\}$, i.e. with $n_i\ne 1$. In fact, I am interested in the order of this sum as $k\to\infty$.

Without the additional assumption $n_i\ne1$, this is a well known problem (see e.g. [Number of ways to write n as a sum of k nonnegative integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217597/number-of-ways-to-write-n-as-a-sum-of-k-nonnegative-integers)) and the result is $\binom{n+k−1}{n} = O(k^n)$. How does the order change for my sum? I expect it to be much smaller.

Comment: Do you consider $3+2+3=8$ different than $2+3+3$?

Comment: Yes, they should be counted twice.

Comment: Although it doesn't give much in the way of intuition for order of magnitude, this could be answered via generating functions.  The number of ways to write $n$ as the sum of $k$ positive integers is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $(x^2+x^3+\dots)^k$.  If you allow zeroes to be used as well, then it is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $(1+x^2+x^3+\dots)^k$

Comment: The relation to the expansion of $(1+x^2+x^3+\dots)^k$ is fine. But how should one proceed from there? I have never worked with generating functions.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it right from the beginning: $n_i=0$ should be allowed.

Comment: As an aside, as $n$ grows large, if you consider the probability that at least one of the entries in the summation is $1$, it will grow small.  In fact, *almost surely* (i.e. "with probability =1") for "large" $n$, there will be no ones among the $n_i$.  This implies that to correct the count from the original, we only remove an insignificant amount from our count, implying it will still be on the same order as before.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the variables. I now fixed everything. I want $k\to\infty$. For $n\to\infty$, the order does not change as mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering the question for if zeroes are not allowed:

We have the following system:

$\begin{cases} n_1+n_2+\dots+n_k=n\\
n_i\in \Bbb Z\\
n_i\geq 2\end{cases}$

By making a change of variable, setting $m_i=n_i-2$ we have the related system:

$\begin{cases}m_1+m_2+\dots+m_k=n-2k\\
m_i\in\Bbb Z\\
m_i\geq 0\end{cases}$

This is in a known form matching your previous question with answer $\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}$

Allowing $j$ zeroes to be used:

- pick which entries are zero
- apply the same process as above to the remaining entries

For specifically $j$ zeroes being used, without loss of generality, the first $j$ entries, we have the system $\begin{cases} n_{j+1}+n_{j+2}+\dots+n_k=n\\
n_i\in\Bbb Z\\
n_i\geq 2\end{cases}$

Making a change of variable, $\begin{cases} m_{j+1}+m_{j+2}+\dots+m_k=n-2(k-j)\\
m_i\in \Bbb Z\\
m_i\geq 0\end{cases}$

This is in a known form with $\binom{n-2(k-j)+(k-j)-1}{k-j-1}=\binom{n-k+j-1}{k-j-1}$

The total then is:

$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k−1} \binom{k}{j}\binom{n-k+j-1}{k-j-1} = \sum\limits_{j\ge k−\frac{n}{2}}^{k−1} \binom{k}{j}\binom{n-k+j-1}{k-j-1}$$

Comment: The idea is great. Thanks. There must be $n_i\ge2$ instead of $n_i\ge1$? Otherwise, you count also possibilities with one as summand.

Comment: @Marcel Oh, whoops.  Indeed, I made a mistake.  I'll fix it.  The approach still works otherwise,

Answer (score 1):

Let $t(n)$ be the number you are interested in and let $c(n,k)$ be the number of way that $n$ can be written as the sum of $k$ distinct nonnegative numbers. Then, 
$$c(n,k) \ge t(n) \ge c(n,k) - k\cdot c(n-1,k-1)$$
because $c(n-1,k-1)$ counts all those decompositions where $n_1=1$, or all those decompositions where $n_2=1$, etcetera. Of course we have subtracted too much, inclusion-exclusion and all, but note that 
$c(n,k) - k\cdot c(n-1,k-1)$ is still on the order of $n^k$. Hence, $t(n)$ is also on the order of $n^k$.

Answer (score 1):

If $T(n,k)$ is the answer, we have
$$ \eqalign{T(n,0) &= \cases{1 & if $n=0$\cr
                             0 & otherwise}\cr
             T(n,k+1) &= T(n,k) + \sum_{j=2}^n T(n-j,k)\cr}$$
This has generating function $$G(x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty T(n,k) x^n y^k = \dfrac{1-x}{1-x-y+xy-x^2y}$$

This can be written as $$G(x,y) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( 1 - \frac{x^2}{1-x}\right)^k y^k$$
or as
$$ G(x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(y) x^n$$
where
$$ a_n(y) = \left(\left( 1+3y+\sqrt {1+2y-3\,{y}^{2}} \right)  \left( 1-y-\sqrt {
1+2y-3\,{y}^{2}} \right) ^{n}+ \left(1+3y- \sqrt {1+2y-3\,{y}^{2}
} \right)  \left( 1-y+\sqrt {1+2y-3\,{y}^{2}} \right) ^{n}
\right)/\left((2+4y-6\,{y}^{2}) (2-2y)^n\right)
$$
Each $a_n$ is actually a rational function with denominator $(1-y)^{\lfloor 1+n/2\rfloor}$ for $n \ne 1$. In particular, it has radius of convergence $1$ for all $n \ne 1$.  The asymptotics of $T(n,k)$ as $k \to \infty$ for fixed $n$ are governed by the coefficient of $(1-y)^{-\lfloor 1+n/2\rfloor}$ in its partial fraction expansion.  It appears that we have 
$$T(n,k) \sim \cases{k^{n/2}/(n/2)! & if $n$ is even\cr k^{(n-1)/2}/((n-3)/2)! & if $n \ge 3$ is odd\cr}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any good book are summary on how to work properly with generating functions?