# Find a formula for the number of solutions to...

Tags: proof-verification

Find a formula for the number of solutions to
$$
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \ldots + x_k = n
$$
where $n \ge 0$ and the the $x_i$ are non-negative integers. For instance, if $n > 0$ then there
is exactly one solution to $x_1 = n$. There are $n + 1$ solutions to $x_1 + x_2 = n$. How many
solutions to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = n$ are there when $k = 3$? Make a table of values
for various $n$ and $k$ and generalize your answer for $k > 3$.

I'm not sure how to start on this question but it's somehow related to n!

Comment: See this answer. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217597/number-of-ways-to-write-n-as-a-sum-of-k-nonnegative-integers

Comment: See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** there is an interesting interpretation of your question: Suppose, for instance, $k=3$ and $n=5$. Then draw $n$ balls and $k-1$ walls, in some order:
$$
\circ\circ\mid\circ\mid\circ\circ
$$
This can be interpreted as the number 5 written as $2+1+2$. Using this idea, can you solve the question?