# In how many ways can N be written as a sum of positive numbers less or equal to K?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I'm trying to solve an informatics problem, and I need to know if there is a formula that can be applied to solve the problem.

Any help appreciated!

Edit: This question was flagged as a possible duplicate of some other question. I want to clarify that the number of numbers added is arbitrary, though the numbers added must be less or equal to K.

Comment: If you consider $3 = 2+1$ and $3 = 1+2$ to be the _same way_ of writing $3$ as a sum of positive numbers, then there is very little in the way of formulas, even without the size restriction. The relevant buzzword is _partition_, and you may see [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts) on that problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of ways to write n as a sum of k nonnegative integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217597/number-of-ways-to-write-n-as-a-sum-of-k-nonnegative-integers)

Comment: There is no simple formula, but there is a simple algorithm that the computer can use to do the calculation.  Would that be helpful?

Comment: @MJD Yes, it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Okay, and do you want to consider $4 = 2 +1+1$ as being the _same_ way as $4 = 1 + 2 + 1$ and $4 = 1+1+2$, or are those three different ways?

Comment: They are different.

Answer (score 2):

This function will calculate the answer:

```
number_of_partitions(N, max):
    if      N = 0:   return 1
    else if N < 0:    return 0
    else:
        total ← 0
        for i in 1 … max do:
            total ← total + number_of_partitions(N-i, max)
        return total
```

For example, `number_of_partitions(4,2)` returns $5$, because it is counting

$$\begin{align}
4 &= 1+1+1+1\\
4 &= 2 + 1 +1 \\
4 &= 1 + 2 + 1 \\
4 &= 1 + 1 + 2 \\
4 &= 2 + 2
\end{align}$$

but not $$\begin{align}4 & = 3 +1 \\ 4& = 1+3\\4 & = 4.\end{align}$$

How does this work?  The recursion is the important part.  We are going to take the original number $N$ and split off parts one at a time.  The part we split off can be any size $i$ from $1$ up to $max$.  Then we count how many ways there are to partition the remainder $N-i$ and add up the results for each $i$.

The only subtle point is in the base case for the recursion.  `number_of_partitions(0, max)` is always 1, because there is exactly one partition of $N=0$, namely the empty partition.

This counting considers $1+1+2$ to be distinct from $2+1+1$. If you want them to be the same, do the recursion with `total ← total + number_of_partitions(N-i, i)` instead, and it will only count the ways which are sorted largest-to-smallest.